Cannot find icuucd75.dll
I'm tring to use International Componenets for Unicode (ICU) APIs in C building with CMake and using as vcpkg as package manager, but when I execute a simple code to test the effective presence of ICU libraries pops up a Windows message box that says to me that the code cannot be executed because icuucd75.dll is missing.

Now I tried to use only uchar.h functionality, but I'm looking for ustdio.h UFILE to read Unicode files, am I doing something wrong?
I tried to find that library to check if it was only a build error, but the libary there isn't, but there are other ICU libraries like icu.dll, icuin.dll and icuuc.dll. Then I searched on Google if someone other had the same problem, but I didn't found nothing.
Does someone knows something about it, or only link me to another answer?
As suggested by @Tsyvarvev in comments this is a screenshot of the error message box (the language is Italian):


"a Windows message box that says to me that ..." - Do not describe the error message. Instead, add it to the question post exactly as it is. Also, do not use images for represent a code; instead post the code as text: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

I'm sorry, I'm not English or American, I tought that the language could be a problem, I will update the question as soon as possible.

The debug versions of the ICU libraries do not exist on Windows. You do not need to link with them anyway. Debug your own code, not ICU’s: Link with icuuc.dll. (You would otherwise have to compile your own icuucd.dll to link with it.)
